# grammar for binary number in base n

Tags: formal-grammars, context-sensitive

given a binary number b, is there any grammar that generates the languages of $1^x$ where $x$ is $b$ in base $n$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) e.g. if $b$ is 1100, the grammar should generates $11,1^{12},1^{36},\cdots$. is there any idea that helps to create the proper grammar?

Comment: Grammars don't have input. Perhaps you could repeat the exact question you were asked?

Comment: consider the grammar for a fixed binary number.

Comment: I don't understand your output format, but it seems that your language is finite.

Comment: No, Since the set of natural numbers are infinite, this language is infinite too. The language L represented above is L = {1^x | x = n^3+n^2+1, n\in N}. Is it not clear? It's my first question here.

Comment: Please rephrase your question in a way that makes it clear what $L$ is, given a binary number (in your last example, presumably 1101 rather than 1100).

Comment: sorry, I meant 1100. the question is: given a binary number **b**, is there any grammar that generates the languages of `1^x` where `x` is  **b** in base n (`n \in \mathbb{N}`)

Comment: This shouldn't be a comment, but rather part of the question. Nobody should need to read the comments in order to understand the question.

Comment: @Yuval is it reasonable now?

Comment: Asked again by different user: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/69514/is-unary-language-with-polynomial-power-context-sensitive.